# What is the correct declaration of string concatenation of html links in c#

Tags: c#, string

I have a project in C# (Winforms) that gets data from REST API. I declared the string wrong. I have problems putting quotes here because of the spaces

I have problems here in particular: `Under % 20Investigation % 2C % 20Pending"%2C%20"In % 20Progress"%2C%20Reopened%2C%20"On % 20Hold`

```
string url = "http://jira.ncr.com/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project%20in%20(project%2C%20project%2C%20project%2C%20project%2C%20project)%20AND%20status%20in%20("Under%20Investigation%2C%20Pending"%2C%20"In%20Progress"%2C%20Reopened%2C%20"On%20Hold")&startAt=0&maxResults=100&fields=key,summary,labels";
```

Comment: you need to escape your quotes. Try to put slash `\\` before every quote

Comment: Add `@` at the beginning of your string. Before quote.

Comment: @FCin this won't help him to solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape string like

```
"http://jira.ncr.com/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project%20in%20(project%2C%20project%2C%20project%2C%20project%2C%20project)%20AND%20status%20in%20(\"Under%20Investigation%2C%20Pending\"%2C%20\"In%20Progress\"%2C%20Reopened%2C%20\"On%20Hold\")&startAt=0&maxResults=100&fields=key,summary,labels"
```

Maybe using Encode would be better solution, i guess...

Worked for this case
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'd still get error... bit struggling this easy task :D

Comment: Refer to this, might be more helpful, 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try adding '@' at the beginning of the string url, anything in the string that would normally be interpreted as an escape sequence is ignored.